# When will the LRU algorithm be miss 100%?

Tags: algorithm, caching, lru, page-replacement

I know these two ways to make LRU algorithm miss 100%.

1. Cyclic accesses to a data-set that is marginally larger than the cache size.

[image]

2. Arbitrary bursts of accesses to an infrequently accessed data-set that pollutes the cache by replaceing the more frequently used entries.

[image]

Red color means cache miss.

But it has another way that "Accesses to blocks with varying access frequencies".

I don't know how to describe it with an example.

Comment: How the first 2 methods are different? (according to your example)

Comment: Arbitrary bursts and varying frequencies sound more like situations where LRU will have **a high, but 100%,** miss rate. A generalisation of cyclic accesses (phrased according to the distance between accesses of the same element) is the only way to guarantee 100% misses.

Comment: Did you get those 3 out of a textbook or something?

Answer (score 1):

LRU might take into account the frequency we access the data, for example:

```
Data   1    1    2    2    3    4
Cache1 1(1) 1(2) 1(2) 1(2) 1(2) 1(2)
Cache2           2(1) 2(2) 2(2) 2(2)
Cache3                     3(1) 4(1)
```

Here is in round brackets a counter which get increased each time there is a cache hit to a corresponding block. So, since we accessed block 1 and 2 two times at the beginning, block 3 get evicted from the cache, despite it was used more recently than block 1 and 2.

So "Accesses to blocks with varying access frequencies" basically might look like this:

```
Data   1    1    2    2    3    4    3    4
Cache1 1(1) 1(2) 1(2) 1(2) 1(2) 1(2) 1(2) 1(2)
Cache2           2(1) 2(2) 2(2) 2(2) 2(2) 2(2)
Cache3                     3(1) 4(1) 3(1) 4(1)
```

So despite we use just 3 and 4, LRU still prefers to keep 1 and 2 as more frequently used.

Another example might be just like your previous examples: we should access blocks just once, so the counter never get increased, i.e.:

```
Data   1    2    3    4    1    2    3
Cache1 1(1) 1(1) 1(1) 4(1) 4(1) 4(1) 3(1)
Cache2      2(1) 2(1) 2(1) 1(1) 1(1) 1(1)
Cache3           3(1) 3(1) 3(1) 2(1) 2(1)
```

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: @Wonter it is a combination of LRU with LFU, i.e. LFRU. Since you asked about "varying access **frequencies**" in context of LRU, I thought that might be it...